# Phpfastcache 6.1.4: Redis is not installed or is misconfigured

Tags: php, phpfastcache

phpfastcache v6.1.4 and redis is up running on default port 6379 through Kubernetes.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught phpFastCache\Exceptions\phpFastCacheDriverCheckException: Redis is not installed or is misconfigured, cannot continue. 
Also, please verify the suggested dependencies in composer because as of the V6, 3rd party libraries are no longer required. in /Users/my-path/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/src/phpFastCache/Drivers/Redis/Driver.php:46
```

In the `config.php`.

```
return [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'maxRetries' => 3,
    'config' => [
        'defaultTtl' => 900,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 6379,
        'database' => 11,
        'password' => 'some password',
        'timeout' => 3,
    ],
];
```

So how to setup the Redis config properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered you on the Github Discussion [here](https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache/discussions/880#discussioncomment-3474640).

You either missed the php-redis extension or the php.ini configuration.

However the version 6.1.4 of pfc is no longer supported, I strongly encourage you to upgrade to 8.1 or 9.x.